# Patrón Redux para navegaciones en Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, redux

resulta que tengo los siguientes componentes A, B, C, D y X. Cada uno de ellos se encuentra en una URL distinta.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La cosa está que cuando pulso sobre un botón en el componente X me gustaría acceder al componente origen de la navegación. Es decir, si yo he iniciado la navegación desde el componente A, desde el componente X volver a A y lo mismo para C y X.
No se como plantear esto en Redux por si alguien podría ayudarme.

Muchas gracias, saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Usando NgRx podrías crear una acción que se llame setOrigin

```js
// src/app/navigation.actions.ts

import { createAction } from '@ngrx/store';

export const setOrigin = createAction(
  '[Navigation] Set Origin',
  props<{payload: {componentUrl: string}}>(),
 );
```

Creas también un reducer

```js
// src/app/navigation.actions.ts

import { createReducer, on } from '@ngrx/store';
import { increment, decrement, reset } from './counter.actions';
 
export const initialState = { navigationOrigin: '' };
 
const _navigationReducer = createReducer(initialState,
  on(setOrigin, (state, { componentUrl}) => state = { 
   ...state, navigationOrigin: componentUrl
  }),
);
 
export function navigationReducer(state, action) {
  return _navigationReducer(state, action);
}
```

En el componente X puedes disparar una acción cuando el componente se crea, guardando la ruta que quieres conservar.

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Store, select } from '@ngrx/store';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { setOrigin } from '../navigation.actions';
 
@Component({
  selector: 'app-x-component',
  templateUrl: './x.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./x.component.css'],
})
export class MyCounterComponent implements OnInit {
  count$: Observable<number>;
 
  constructor(
    private router: Router,
    private store: Store<{ navigationOrigin: string }>
  }
 
  ngOnInit() {
    this.store.dispatch(setOrigin(this.router.url))
  }
}
```

En el componente A o C puedes acceder al valor de la ruta de esta manera

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Store, select } from '@ngrx/store';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
 
@Component({
  selector: 'app-a-component',
  templateUrl: './a.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./a.component.css'],
})
export class MyCounterComponent implements OnInit {
  navigationOrigin$: Observable<string>;
 
  constructor(
    private router: Router,
    private store: Store<{ navigationOrigin: string }>
  ) {
    this.navigationOrigin$ = store.pipe(select('navigationOrigin'));
  }
 
}
```

```html
<a routerLink="navigationOrigin$ | async"> Regresar al origen </a>
```